# Instead of using synchronized keyword i am using lock concept but i am not getting the output as i got in synchronized key word?

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

class Displayx
{
    public void wish(String name)
    {
        ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        //using locks
        lock.lock();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            {
                System.out.print("Good Morning : ");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("I got intruppted");
                }
                System.out.println(name);
            } 
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
class MyThreadex2 extends Thread
{
    Displayx d;
    String name;
    public MyThreadex2(Displayx d, String name) 
    {
        this.d = d;
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        d.wish(name);
    }
}
public class ReentrantLockDemo1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Displayx d = new Displayx();
        MyThreadex2 mt1 = new MyThreadex2(d, "SHOAIB");
        MyThreadex2 mt2 = new MyThreadex2(d, "RAHUL");

        mt1.start();
        mt2.start();

    }

}
```

output i am getting is

```
Good Morning : Good Morning : SHOAIB
Good Morning : RAHUL
Good Morning : RAHUL
Good Morning : SHOAIB
Good Morning : SHOAIB
Good Morning : RAHUL
Good Morning : RAHUL
Good Morning : SHOAIB
Good Morning : SHOAIB
Good Morning : RAHUL
Good Morning : SHOAIB
Good Morning : RAHUL
Good Morning : SHOAIB
Good Morning : RAHUL
Good Morning : RAHUL
Good Morning : SHOAIB
Good Morning : SHOAIB
Good Morning : RAHUL
Good Morning : RAHUL
SHOAIB
```

Comment: Use the **same** `Lock`? Just like you would need to `synchronize` on the same `Object`. In fact in this case there is no benefit to using `Lock` - it comes into its own when locks needs to interleaved...

Comment: Perhaps more importantly, **don't `extends Thread`**. (unless you know what you are doing and have good cause)

Comment: @BoristheSpider Why not `extends Thread`? Please link to article explaining why.

Comment: [There you go](http://stackoverflow.com/q/541487/2071828) @Andreas.

Comment: I see recommendations, about flexibility, reuse, coding to interface, and the like, but your *"unless you know what you are doing and have good cause"* makes it sound *dangerous* to extend Thread, and I don't see that. Maybe I just misinterpreted what you said?

Comment: @Andreas it can be rather dangerous - for example using `wait` and `notify` on a `Thread` can have rather unexpected consequences as `Thread` notifies itself internally on death. It's generally best avoided for all sorts of reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();` outside of your method.

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
         public void  wish(String name)
         {
             //using locks
             lock.lock();
             try {
                 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                     System.out.print("Good Morning : ");
                     try {
                         Thread.sleep(2000);
                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                         System.out.println("I got intruppted");
                     }
                     System.out.println(name);
                 } 
             } finally {
                 lock.unlock();
             }

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, variables created inside the method are accessible (scoped) within the same thread.

**As your `ReentrantLock`  object is created inside the `wish`() method, it is local to each thread.** i.e., you are actually creating individual `lock` objects for each thread, because of which multiple threads are entering into your critical section code (inside the `try` block).

```
class Displayx
{
    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();//Use the same lock object

    public void wish(String name)
    {
        //using locks
        lock.lock();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.print("Good Morning : ");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("I got intruppted");
                }
                System.out.println(name);
            } 
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, as Boris mentioned in the comment, make sure that you are "coding to interfaces" by using `Runnable` or `Callable` interfaces instead of directly extending `Thread` class.